# How to extract and visualize data from OSM file in Python

Tags: python, pandas, openstreetmap, osmium

I have downloaded an OpenStreetMap file on my desktop , and I have used my OSM file in the jupyter notebook.

**My code:**

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
osm_file = "ahmedabad_india.osm"

for event, elem in ET.iterparse(osm_file, events=("start",)):
     print(elem)
     # prints the Element 'osm' at 0x03A7DC08>
     #<Element 'bounds' at 0x03A7DDA0>
     #<Element 'node' at 0x03A7DE90>
     #<Element 'tag' at 0x03A7DF08> and so on ...
```

I'd like to see the contents of all the `tags` i.e.
 `<'node', 'id', 'name', ...>` and so on.

I tried using `elem` tag but, it prints nothing.

Can anyone help me to figure out, who to get the contents of tags like node, ways etc.

Comment: [OSMnx](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io) is a popular Python package to easily download, model, analyze, and visualize street networks and any other geospatial features from OpenStreetMap. It can also load/visualize data from a .osm xml file.

Answer (score 22):

You can extract all the data from an `.osm` file through **[PyOsmium](http://osmcode.org/pyosmium/)** (A fast and flexible C++ library for working with OpenStreetMap data) and then handle it with **[Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)**:

**Code:**

```
import osmium as osm
import pandas as pd

class OSMHandler(osm.SimpleHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        osm.SimpleHandler.__init__(self)
        self.osm_data = []

    def tag_inventory(self, elem, elem_type):
        for tag in elem.tags:
            self.osm_data.append([elem_type, 
                                   elem.id, 
                                   elem.version,
                                   elem.visible,
                                   pd.Timestamp(elem.timestamp),
                                   elem.uid,
                                   elem.user,
                                   elem.changeset,
                                   len(elem.tags),
                                   tag.k, 
                                   tag.v])

    def node(self, n):
        self.tag_inventory(n, "node")

    def way(self, w):
        self.tag_inventory(w, "way")

    def relation(self, r):
        self.tag_inventory(r, "relation")


osmhandler = OSMHandler()
# scan the input file and fills the handler list accordingly
osmhandler.apply_file("muenchen.osm")

# transform the list into a pandas DataFrame
data_colnames = ['type', 'id', 'version', 'visible', 'ts', 'uid',
                 'user', 'chgset', 'ntags', 'tagkey', 'tagvalue']
df_osm = pd.DataFrame(osmhandler.osm_data, columns=data_colnames)
df_osm = tag_genome.sort_values(by=['type', 'id', 'ts'])
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: my concern is how do you get the .osm file in the first place. Is there an automated pythonic way to get such a file? Also is there no direct way to access the data without have to download some physical file in the process which would eat up system resources?

Comment: you can simply go to the osm website, select a small region and export it.

Comment: How to get latitude and longitude of elements?

Comment: @VictorMarconi if you write print(elem) below the definition of tag_inventory you can see that the coordinates are stored like this `location=8.786805/53.074942` this means that elem.location will give you the value

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but I am looking to plot relations. As far as I can tell the resulting dataframe does not contain the members of a relation and also does not contain coordinates for nodes. How can this information be added?

Comment: what does the `visible` column represent?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a full explanation on downloading features from OSM and visualizing it in Python. **I do not recommend writing Python to read `.osm` files** because there's a lot of easy to use software (e.g. GDAL) that handles that for you.

**You do not need to handle nodes, ways, and relations individually to use OpenStreetMap data.**

## 1. Choose the feature from OpenStreetMap

All features are *tagged* with metadata like [name (`name=Starbucks`)](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:name), [building type (`building=university`)](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:building), or [business hours (`opening_hours=Mo-Fr 08:00-12:00,13:00-17:30`)](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:opening_hours). For example, the Roman Colosseum is tagged as so:

[image: OpenStreetMap tags on the Roman colosseum]

To download a subset of OSM features, first decide a list of tag keys and (optionally) values to filter for. For example, all restaurants with names would be filtered for `amenity=restaurant` and `name=*`.

Useful resources for exploring the appropriate tags for your use case are the [OSM TagInfo](https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org) website and the [OSM Wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Main_Page).

For this example we'll download and visualize `building=university`.

## 2. Download matching features

There are three main ways to download data from OpenStreetMap, each with pros and cons.

#### a. Download features from OpenStreetMap as `.geojson` using an API

This method is the least resource intensive (no server required), does not require installing GDAL, and can be done with the entire planet. It requires a [free API key](https://buntinglabs.com/account/register) for a third party [OSM extract API](https://buntinglabs.com/solutions/openstreetmap-extracts).

1. `curl`/`wget` to the endpoint and specify the features to download

```
curl --get 'https://osm.buntinglabs.com/v1/osm/extract' \
     --data "tags=building=university" \
     --data "api_key=YOUR_API_KEY" \
     -o university_buildings.geojson
```

This downloads all features on the planet satisfying your `tags=` filter as GeoJSON to `university_buildings.geojson`.

You don't need to convert between file formats. If you want a small extract, you can pass the `bbox=` parameter and build a bounding box at [bboxfinder](http://bboxfinder.com/).

#### b. Download region as `.osm` and manually extract locally

This method can be done 100% locally but requires using a small region (max ~10 neighborhoods) and [installing GDAL](https://gdal.org/download.html).

1. Zoom to and download the `.osm` file from [OpenStreetMap Extract](https://www.openstreetmap.org/export). This will be a large file because it's in XML format
2. Filter `.osm` file for features you want to keep. See below (c.) for example with `osmium`.
3. Use ogr2ogr to transform `.osm` to `.geojson`. This step is complex because GDAL stores points, lines, and polygons as separate polygons. [This tutorial](https://www.compose.com/articles/how-to-transform-and-use-openstreetmap-data-into-geojson-using-gdal/) shows how to convert `.osm` to `.geojson`, or see below (c.) for example.

#### c. Download planet as `.osm.pbf` and extract on a server

This method is resource-intensive and requires 100GB+ in disk storage, ~2 days of processing time, and 64GB+ in RAM. However, it lets you search the entire planet. It requires [installing GDAL](https://gdal.org/download.html).

1. Torrent the [`planet.osm.pbf`](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm) or download a region extract from [Geofabrik Extracts](https://download.geofabrik.de)
2. Filter for your target features using [`osmium-tags-filter`](https://docs.osmcode.org/osmium/latest/osmium-tags-filter.html):

```
osmium tags-filter -o university_buildings.osm.pbf planet.osm.pbf nwr/building=university
```

3. Convert the `university_buildings.osm.pbf` file to a `.geojson`

Depending on the size of your output file, it may be too large for GeoJSON (which is text-based), and you should instead use a GeoPackage (`.gpkg`) or FlatGeobuf (`.fgb`).

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON output_points.json input.osm.pbf points
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON output_lines.json input.osm.pbf lines
# ... continue for multilinestrings, multipolygons and other_relations
```

Then join the `output_points.json`, `output_lines.json`, etc with [`ogrmerge.py`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogrmerge.html).

## 3. Visualize features

After downloading, best practice is to load the data into [geopandas](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/), a [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org) extension with built-in spatial support. This is the easiest way to visualize spatial data in Python.

We'll load the data into a `GeoDataFrame` and then plot it with [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd

# Read our downloaded file from earlier
gdf = gpd.read_file('university_buildings.geojson', driver='GeoJSON')

# Plot and individually add each building name
ax = gdf.plot()
for x, y, label in zip(gdf.centroid.x, gdf.centroid.y, gdf.name):
    ax.annotate(label, xy=(x, y), xytext=(3, 3), textcoords="offset points")

plt.show()
```

This gives a result like so:

[image: OpenStreetMap buildings plotted in Python and geopandas]