# Getting an error while processing data with pandas

Tags: python, openstreetmap

I want to display data from `.pbf (open street map, xml format) file.` I [have seen this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45771809/how-to-extract-and-visualize-data-from-osm-file-in-python), but I get an error:

```
NameError: name 'tag_genome' is not defined
```

Is sth wrong in his code?

**EDITED QUESTION:**

I edited his code a little, got a code:

```
df_osm = pd.DataFrame(handler.osm_data, columns=data_colnames)
tag_genome = pd.DataFrame(columns=data_colnames)

df_osm = tag_genome.sort_values(by=['type', 'id', 'ts'])

print(df_osm.head())
```

returns:

> Empty DataFrame
>
> Columns: [type, id, version, visible, ts, uid, user, chgset, ntags, tagkey, tagvalue]
>
> Index: []

Why It says that `dataframe` is empty, when `pbf file` is existing..

Comment: It doesn't work because the name `tag_genome` is not defined yet the code is trying to use it.

Comment: @wwii I see, but I do not understand what should be instead of tag_genome to show me table in his answer below

Comment: Provide a [mcve] (including data) with emphasis on minimal and someone might be able to help.

Comment: Python doesn't know what `tag_genome` is, because you didn't assign it. You didn't to something like `tag_genome = pd.DataFrame(array)`, or something. You need to assign a value to it before you use it.

Comment: @nicolasgervais I edited my question, please see

Comment: in `tag_genome = pd.DataFrame(columns=data_colnames)`, you just created an empty DataFrame with column names. The argument `columns` in `pd.DataFrame` only refers to the column _names_, it doesn't copy entire columns from another DataFrame.