# How to create a dataframe from an osm file with a geometry column

Tags: python, postgresql, openstreetmap

I have done what @mforezdev suggests in the following thread with osmium and pandas libraries:

[How to extract and visualize data from OSM file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45771809/how-to-extract-and-visualize-data-from-osm-file-in-python)

I created a dataframe from my .osm file and then inserted its elements in a table in PostgreSQL. Then, i want to insert the table from PostgreSQL to QGIS as a vector layer. But, my data have not geometry reference.

So, i tried to append elem.location at the osm_data list in the tag_inventory function, but it didn't work.

I can't find how to get the geometry column from my .osm file.

Does anyone know how can i do this?